# Cannot find method for trim() for variable price double

Tags: java

> Hi, Im trying to fix this small error with the trim().The error
>   message that is being displayed is cannot find symbol method trim()
>   and location is of variable price type double. Below is the code. /* 
>   * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates  * and open the template in the editor.  */ package helper;
>
> import bean.ProductBean; import java.sql.ResultSet; import
>   java.sql.SQLException; import java.text.ParseException; import
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
>
> public class ProductHelper {
>
> ```
> static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
>
> public static void populateaddproduct(ProductBean addproduct, HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {
>     String rowid = request.getParameter("rowid");
>     if (rowid != null && rowid.trim().length() > 0) {
>         addproduct.setRowid(new Integer(rowid));
>     }
>     addproduct.setEan(request.getParameter("ean"));
>     addproduct.setPip(request.getParameter("pip"));
>     addproduct.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
>     addproduct.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));
>     addproduct.setSupplier(request.getParameter("supplier"));
>     **Double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
>     if (price != null && price.trim().length() > 0) {
>         addproduct.setPrice(new Double(price));**
>     }
>     String expiryDate = request.getParameter("expirydate");
>     if (expiryDate != null && expiryDate.trim().length() == SDF.toPattern().length()) {
>         addproduct.setExpiryDate(SDF.parse(expiryDate));
>     }
>     addproduct.setLatest(request.getParameter("latestproduct"));
>     addproduct.setDiscounted(request.getParameter("discount"));
>
> }
>
> public static void populateProduct(ProductBean product, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
>     product.setRowid(rs.getInt("id"));
>     product.setEan(rs.getString("ean"));
>     product.setPip(rs.getString("pip"));
>     product.setName(rs.getString("name"));
>     product.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
>     product.setSupplier(rs.getString("supplier"));
>     product.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
>     product.setExpiryDate(rs.getDate("expirydate"));
>     product.setLatest(rs.getString("latestproduct"));
>     product.setDiscounted(rs.getString("discount"));
>
> } }
> ```

Comment: ok so how can i fix this for double ?

Comment: The error is completely correct.  What you're trying to do doesn't actually make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `trim()` method removes leading and trailing whitespace from a *string*. The type of `double` is numeric - the very concept of whitespace does not apply to it. You do not need to trim a `double` - it is always implicitly trimmed.

If you read a `String` that *represents* a `double`, however, you may need to trim it. The type of the variable needs to be `String`, not `Double`, in order for the `trim()` method to apply. Obviously, if you need to use the value as a `double` later on, you need to convert the string to a double, for example by calling the [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String priceStr = request.getParameter("price");
if (priceStr != null && priceStr.trim().length() != 0) {
    addproduct.setPrice(Double.valueOf(priceStr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**price** is of type `Double`. `java.lang.Double` doesn't have `trim()` method.`trim()` is a method which removes leading and trailing spaces for a `java.lang.String`

I think just the null check is fine here.you don't really need to check the length.

```
    if (price != null)
```